# Dust.js with inline JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dust.js

I want to create a dust.js template but with inline javascript function. It that possible? The problem is with single '{' as a template character.

For instance:

```
<html>
...
<body>
<script>
  function test(var) { alert('Hi {name} with ' + var); };
</script>
  Hello {name} 
</html>
```

Can I switch dust's special char to "{{"?

PS. I know that there's {~rb} but using it with inline JS would be a horror.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works for me. Because you have parentheses, curly braces, and spaces inside of your curly braces, the content within the curly braces is not parsed as a Dust reference. Those characters are not legal characters for Dust references.

Try it out [here](http://www.dustjs.com/) for LinkedIn Dust or [here](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/) for akdubya Dust.

Comment: Yeah, your right. Any special character forces Dust to ignore the expression. And there's another thing one has to be aware of while writing JS code with Dust: brackets must have at least one white character inside. This way Dust will always ignore the content.